# My new CSProj is using SDK format but MVC Razor views are targetting AspNetCore and not AspNet

Tags: razor, view, sdk, csproj

I've created a ASP.NET Web Application .NET Framework project, and when I convert the CSProj file to use SDK format, my Razor view targets Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper instead of System.Web.Mvc HtmlHelper.

Is this a feature of the SDK projects? 
Is there is no support for Razor in a .Net Framework world at this time? 
Will there be?

The new MsBuild format is so nice ... I want it for my projects, REALLY badly.

Comment: How did you do the conversion?

Comment: Built by hand. No conversion, this is not an old 2017 project that got upgraded. I think the new project SDK simply doesn't support ASP.NET Framework MVC/Razor, only the AspNetCore version and I think it's a setting in the OS not MsBuild, the project, the solution, or the IDE. :( I couldn't figure it out.